# MemoryError in for loop python

Tags: python, list

I have a script with result must be the minimum number of lists in one list. I have some data list and the items of this list have to be sorted: if item is smaller than B put it to the list sol and detract item from B, else put it to next list of lists sol. It is like bin packing problem. But I have got MemoryError in this case.

```
B = 60
data = [35,21,40,12,24]
max = [B]
sol = [[]]
temp = []
for item in data:
    for j,free in enumerate(max):
        if free >= item:
            max[j] -= (item)
            sol[j].append(item)
            print(max)
            print(sol)
            break
        else:
            sol.append([item])
            max.append(B-item)

solved = len(sol)
print(solved)
print(sol)
```

The output will be like:

3
[[35,21],[40,12],[24]]

The error is occurred in line after else:. I appreciate any help or advice. Thank you!

Comment: What is `remain` and what is `k`?

Comment: I edited it, it was some mistakes in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A memory error is where your program literally runs out of memory to use.

In your case, it is because you have created an infinite loop which just keeps adding elements to `sol` until there is no more room.

If you put a `print` at the top of the `if` statement like in the code below, you will see your problem in the terminal.

```
B = 60
data = [35,21,40,12,24]
max = [B]
sol = [[]]
temp = []
for item in data:
    for j,free in enumerate(max):
        print(max)
        if free >= item:
            max[j] -= (item)
            sol[j].append(item)
            print(max)
            print(sol)
            break
        else:
            sol.append([item])
            max.append(B-item)

solved = len(sol)
print(solved)
print(sol)
```

Comment: Oh I see... Thank you! Do you have any suggestion to correct it?

Comment: Can you post a correct sample output of that dataset?

Comment: The output will be like:
    3
    [[35,21],[40,12],[24]]